# Turn string data (of GPS coordinates) into a GPS tracker = frozen map. QGIS2.14/Py2.7/Win7/LAN

Tags: gps, qgis-2, python-2.7

I am currently involved in a student project which is to turn string GPS coordinates into a GPS tracker. This is my current work: First, the UDP data is shared through a LAN (No internet available) therefore, I get it with an UDP socket. The frame: (DDS coordinates)

```
"lat+4542000lon-00019590alt+658"
```

Then I translate it in DD coordinates so that I can show it on the map using this code:

```py
plane=QgsVertexMarker(canvas)
plane.setColor(QColor("blue"))
plane.setIconSize(10)
plane.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_CROSS)
plane.setPenWidth(3)
plane.setCenter(QgsPoint(lon,lat))
plane.show()
```

With 1 mark it works very well. But I receive new frame every second and I'd like to move this mark simultaneously. That's why I tried this:

```py
#I assumed that the first point is already shown
while n<3600:
    data,addr=sock.recvfrom(1024)
    lat,lon,alt=prepare(data)
    plane.hide()
    plane.setCenter(QgsPoint(lon,lat))
    plane.show()
    n+=1
```

But when I run this, Qgis is frozen until the last mark appears while I expect to see one mark after another and to run QGIS normally.
How can I fix it?
--QGIS 2.14, Python 2.7, Windows 7 32bits, no internet--

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are working with QGIS 2.14?

Comment: Yes, in fact this project is for an aeroclub which uses QGIS 2.14. Do you think it causes difficulties?

Comment: I have no idea, I just know that newer versions of QGIS tend to incorporate more/better working functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your can try the try and except condition to make sure where things goes wrong. Something like this :

```
while n<3600 :
try :
your code
except:
whatever condition you want to test
```

At least if it still doesn't work it should not freeze anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried it but it still doesn't work. So, I tried with a list of coordinates adding time.sleep(1) and it froze again. I concluded that my issue is not specifically linked to my way to get data. Have you any idea where I'm doing wrong?